# How to add a 'skip' button on the Parse login

Tags: ios, email, authentication, parse-platform

I am using the Parse login and giving users the option to create an account or login with facebook to use my app.

Sadly my app was rejected the Apple store for not providing a mechanism for users to skip the login process.

"17.2 We found that your app requires customers to register with personal information to access non-account-based features, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, we noticed that the user is required to enter a email address to be able to access the app.

Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app features and content that are not associated specifically to the user. User registration that requires the sharing of personal information must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality. Additionally, the requested information must be relevant to the features. "

Is there a way to add a 'Skip Login' button to the Parse loginviewcontroller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a button that lets the users bypass the Login screen and go directly to the screen after, maybe even limit the features that require them to login (so that they will eventually sign up).

Answer (score 0):

When user has registered or login using fb account then you need to provide that skip button with functionality that user can bypass that condition and continue using ur app. As this condition are always option and no mandatory. So provide a skip logic in that skip button to skip to main screen of ur app for further usage.

Anything else then let me know.